# How to convert list into string with quotes in python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

i have a list and want it as a string with quotes
`mylist = [1,2,3]`

require O/P as
`myString = "'1','2','3'"`

i tried `mystring = '\',\''.join(mylist)`

it gave me result as

`mystring = "1','2','3"`

first and last quotes (') are missing

Comment: How about you just take the result of your computation, and add single quotes around it as a second step: `mystring = "'"+mystring+"'"`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to be the only solution so far that isn't a hack...

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> ','.join("'{0}'".format(x) for x in mylist)
"'1','2','3'"
```

This can also be written more compactly as:

```
>>> ','.join(map("'{0}'".format, mylist))
"'1','2','3'"
```

Or, using an f-string:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> ','.join(f"'{x}'" for x in mylist)
"'1','2','3'"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> str([str(x) for x in mylist]).strip("[]")
"'1','2','3'"
```

Answer (score 2):

as a simple hack, why don't you..

```
mystring = "'%s'" %"','".join(mylist)
```

wrap the result of your commands in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as well

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mystring = str(map(str, mylist)).strip("[]")
```

Answer (score 1):

OR regular `repr`:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> ','.join(repr(str(i)) for i in l)
"'1','2','3'"
>>>
```