# How do I add quotes to list element which contain / in python

Tags: python

I have the following list

```
a = [ documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg,  documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg]
```

and I want to achieve the following

```
[ "documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg",  "documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg"]
```

I tried this

```
x= ['{0}'.format(i) for i in a]

print x
```

but I get the following error

```
 File "list.py", line 3

    a = [ documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg,  documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg] 
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can I add quotes so as to get

```
[ "documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg",  "documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg"]
```

Comment: Have you tried add them directly in your script ?

Comment: I have tried but its not working , my question is same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054870/how-to-convert-list-into-string-with-quotes-in-python but only the data is different, instead of mylist = [1,2,3] , mine would look something like mylist=[documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg,  documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg]

Comment: it is not, 1,2,3 are int, which is legal sytaxe in python. You should write `mylist=[ "documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg",  "documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg"]`  in your script, you can only pass those caracters as strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me that , I was treating strings like integers

Comment: No problem, hope that solved your problem. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to print a string in quotation marks you can do one of the following:

```
"ASDFG 'those will show' Asdfg"
'ASDFG "Those will show" Asdfg'
"Asdfg \"Those will show\" Asdfg"
```

If you intend on converting the items to a string you do:

```
str(YOUR OBJECT)
```

Maybe your code has a problem with your dot placement. That usually indicates an attribute of a class.

Comment: Thank you for your response , my question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054870/how-to-convert-list-into-string-with-quotes-in-python but instead of mylist=[1,2,3] ,mine would look like mylist=[documents/17361862_n.jpg,  documents/1702gqbi7GG.jpg] , thank you icy TV

Comment: But to add quotes you need the data to be a string right? You could do:
for i in mydata:
 res += "'{}'".format(i)
Or:
res = []
for i in mydata:
 res.append("'{}'".format(i))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add quotation mark at your list, you can do this :

`a = [ "\"documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg\"", "\"documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg\""]`

I am sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you my question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054870/how-to-convert-list-into-string-with-quotes-in-python but my data is a little bit different instead of mylist=[1,2,3] the data looks like mylist= [documents/17361862_1455215234500329_3000435910753279754_n.jpg,  documents/17022254_1431360773552442_8479986202582740765_n_gqbi7GG.jpg] , thanks in advance