# Python: How to add single quotes to a long list

Tags: python, string, list, quotes, nameerror

I want to know the quickest way to add single quotes to each element in a Python list created by hand.

When generating a list by hand, I generally start by creating a variable (e.g. my_list), assigning it to list brackets, and then populating the list with elements, surrounded by single quotes:

`my_list = []`

`my_list = [ '1','baz','ctrl','4' ]`

I want to know if there is a quicker way to make a list, however. The issue is, I usually finish writing my list, and then go in and add single quotes to every element in the list. That involves too many keystrokes, I think.

A quick but not effective solution on Jupyter NB's is, highlighting your list elements and pressing the single quote on your keyboard. This does not work if you have a list of words that you want to turn to strings, however; Python thinks you are calling variables (e.g. my_list = [1, baz, ctrl, 4 ]) and throws a NameError message. In this example, the list element baz would throw:

`NameError: name 'baz' is not defined`

I tried this question on SO, but it only works if your list already contains strings: [Join a list of strings in python and wrap each string in quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007686/join-a-list-of-strings-in-python-and-wrap-each-string-in-quotation-marks/12007737). This question also assumes you are only working with numbers: [How to convert list into string with quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054870/how-to-convert-list-into-string-with-quotes-in-python).

I am not working on a particular project at the moment. This question is just for educational purposes. Thank you all for your input/shortcuts.

Comment: @Julien I think you deleted it because it can be directly be a list, instead of a string (and if wanted a string do `str(string.split(','))`)

Comment: If some IDE could give plugin support will be better, something like emmet, really doubt anyone will use program to generate it when coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah but then why not:

```
>>> s = 'a,b,cd,efg'
>>> s.split(',')
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'efg']
>>>
```

Then just copy it then paste it in

Or idea from @vash_the_stampede:

```
>>> s = 'a b cd efg'
>>> s.split()
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'efg']
>>>
```

Comment: Is there something better about this compared to `s = 'a b cd efg'`, `s.split()`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede That'a option too

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found was:

```
>>> f = [10, 20, 30]

>>> new_f = [f'{str(i)}' for i in x]

>>> print(new_f)

['10', '20', '30']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take input as string and split it to list
For eg.

```
eg="This is python program"
print(eg)
eg=eg.split()
print(eg)
```

This will give output

> This is python program
>
> ['This', 'is', 'python', 'program']

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I think I've found a quick way following @U10-Forward's idea:

```
>>> list = ('A B C D E F G Hola Hello').split()
>>> print(list)

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Hola', 'Hello']
```